# Is there any networking app for iPhone that can work together with other apps?

Tags: iphone

Is there any networking app for iPhone that can work together with other apps?

Comment: What do you mean by "work together"?  What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called NetworkToolbox for iPhone and iPad which can be integrated with external apps. For example, a remote access app can be used from inside Network Toolbox and vice versa. Network Toolbox can also be started using Safari.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/networktoolbox-network-scanning/id651691453?mt=8